# Enter/Exit animation programmatically using navigation components

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I am using Navigation Components library. When navigating to another fragment, to use animation, I understand that I can add xml code like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/specifyAmountFragment"
    android:name="com.example.buybuddy.buybuddy.SpecifyAmountFragment"
    android:label="fragment_specify_amount"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_specify_amount">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/confirmationAction"
        app:destination="@id/confirmationFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
        app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
        app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right" />
 </fragment>
```

But, I need to use it programmatically.

I would appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer and I just want to share with you.

You can use `NavOptions` in this way:

```
 val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToFilesFragment2()

 val navOptions = NavOptions
   .Builder()
   .setEnterAnim(R.anim.fragment_open_enter)
   .setExitAnim(R.anim.fragment_close_exit)
   .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.fragment_open_enter)
   .setPopExitAnim(R.anim.fragment_close_exit)
   .build()

  findNavController().navigate(action, navOptions)
```

Comment: Do note that, if you have a "PopUpTo" in the nav_graph, writing a new NavOptions.Builder() like this will ignore whatever you had in the nav_graph